# How to add a vmethod to template toolkit when using Dancer?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit, dancer

How to add a [vmethod](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html) to template toolkit when using Dancer?

If there isn't a way, how can I add a function /how to execute a ref to function which is added to the tokens/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a [custom vmethod](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html#section_Defining_Custom_Virtual_Methods)  to TT in [Dancer](http://perldancer.org) requires a bit of messing with the direct TT package variables. I do wish that the [Dancer::Template](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer::Template) object provide access to the underlying template object.

Here is snippet that could go in a Dancer route:

```
package mydancerapp;

use Dancer qw(:syntax);

# make sure TT module is loaded since Dancer loads it later in the request cycle
use Template::Stash;

# create list op vmethod, sorry its pretty trivial
$Template::Stash::LIST_OPS->{ uc_first  } = sub {
    my $list = shift;
    return [ map { ucfirst } @$list ];
);
```

It is probably best to move this into its own module `mydancerapp::TT` or `mydancerapp::TT::VMethods` and then load it in your main application class.

Then you can use it in your templates like:

```
# in route
get '/' => sub {
    template 'index', { veggies => [ qw( radishes lettuce beans squash )] };
};

# in template: views/index.tt
<p>[% veggies.uc_first.join(',') %]</p>
```

If it went well then you should see: `Radishes,Lettuce,Beans,Squash` in your output. :)

Comment: I tried something like this and it didn't work so I post this question.. Now it works ^^

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about adding a vmethod, but I think the second thing can be done like this:

```
hook 'before_template' => sub {
    my $tokens = shift;
    $tokens->{myfunction} = sub { ... };         #  OR ...
    $tokens->{otherfunction} = \&other_func;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In Dancer2, you can do this:

```
hook before => sub {
    my ( $app ) = @_;

    $app->template_engine->engine->context->define_vmethod( 'list' => 'uc_first' => sub {
        my $list = shift;
        return [ map { ucfirst } @$list ];
    });
};
```